# How to Customize PrettyPhoto Buttons now that "pp_link" Class is removed?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, escaping, prettyphoto

PrettyPhoto used to have `<span class="pp_link">` in **jquery.prettyPhoto.js** *Version: 3.1.2*

With that, I was able to add Custom stuff to the Buttons Area `<div class="pp_social">` of the Pop-up Gallery.

*What my HTML was like:*

```
<a href="" rel="prettyPhoto[]">
<img src="" link="&lt;div&gt;---My Custom PHP Code Here---&lt;/div&gt;></a>
```

With that **Escaped HTML** "link" portion (`link="&lt;div&gt;---My Custom PHP Code Here---&lt;/div&gt;`) I **added PHP** and Special Functions where the Twitter and Facebook buttons are.

I am **not able to do this anymore** in the latest **PrettyPhoto version (3.1.5)**.
I was forced to update to this, because of the latest jQuery update.

**Does anyone know the Best or Easiest way for me to add Custom PHP to each of my PrettyPhoto pop-up windows, in PP v3.1.5?**

The Code in there changes depending on the Active Image. That's why I want to add PHP to the HTML, rather than editing the .js file.

Let me know if you guys need more clarification.
Looking forward to your help!
-Andrew

Comment: What do you mean by adding custom PHP?  PHP is on the server side, not the client side.

Comment: Yes the **HTML is on my own Website** and Server. PrettyPhoto is installed on my Server, I use `rel="prettyPhoto[]"` in my HTML to activate PrettyPhoto on my site.

In the `link=""` attribute of the <img> is where I add my PHP. 

The older version of PP would read that and **Unescape** it in the <span class="pp_link">. But now they removed that <span> from the latest .JS, so it isn't working anymore.